# How to make images streamable in NestJS for a backend search engine?

Tags: typescript, file-upload, nestjs, prisma

Currently Im coding a backend search engine where you are able to search for cards, these cards should return their cards images and card stats. Right now I build it so far that the card informations and their stats are send to the client but how do I send the card with images back, I don't have any ideas, so maybe there is someone who is familiar with that.

1. Client will req to the server for the name of the card.
2. User gets card returned with the image and stats for the card.

Here are the File from my Code:
Service File:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PrismaService } from '../prisma/prisma.service';
import { YuGiOhCard, YuGiOhCardImage } from '@prisma/client';

@Injectable()
export class SearchCardService {
constructor(private prisma: PrismaService) {}

async findAllCards(query?: string): Promise\<YuGiOhCard\[\]\> {
return this.prisma.yuGiOhCard.findMany({
where: {
name: {
contains: query,
},
},
include: {
YuGiOhCardImage: true,
},
});
}

async findCardByName(name: YuGiOhCard\['name'\]): Promise\<YuGiOhCard\> {
return this.prisma.yuGiOhCard.findUnique({
where: {
name,
},
include: {
YuGiOhCardImage: true,
},
});
}

async getCardByNameId(
cardNameId: YuGiOhCardImage\['cardNameId'\],
imageUrl: YuGiOhCardImage\['imageUrl'\],
) {
return this.prisma.yuGiOhCardImage.findFirst({
where: {
cardNameId: cardNameId,
AND: {
imageUrl: imageUrl,
},
},
});
}

async returnCardInfo(
cardName: YuGiOhCard\['name'\],
imageUrl: YuGiOhCardImage\['imageUrl'\],
): Promise\<YuGiOhCard\> {
const name = await this.findCardByName(cardName);

    if (name) {
      return this.prisma.yuGiOhCard.findFirst({
        include: {
          YuGiOhCardImage: true,
        },
        where: {
          name: cardName,
          YuGiOhCardImage: {
            some: {
              imageUrl,
            },
          },
        },
      });
    }
    
    return null;

}
}
```

Controller:

```
import { Controller, Get, Param } from '@nestjs/common';
import { SearchCardService } from './search-card.service';
import { YuGiOhCard } from '@prisma/client';
import { StreamingFileController } from '../streaming-file/streaming-file.controller';

@Controller('search-card')
export class SearchCardController {
constructor(private readonly searchCardService: SearchCardService) {}

@Get()
async findAllCards(query?): Promise\<YuGiOhCard\[\]\> {
return this.searchCardService.findAllCards(query);
}

@Get('/:name')
async findCardByName(
@Param('name') name: YuGiOhCard\['name'\],
): Promise\<YuGiOhCard\> {
const getCardByName = await this.searchCardService.findCardByName(name);

    if (getCardByName) {
      const getFile = new StreamingFileController();
      console.log('tetstte');
      await getFile.getFile();
      console.log(getFile);
    
      return getCardByName;
    }

}
}
```

And here is the db schema for the database:

```
// This is your Prisma schema file,
// learn more about it in the docs: https://pris.ly/d/prisma-schema

generator client {
provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
provider = "mysql"
url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model YuGiOhCard {
id               String               @id @default(uuid())
name             String               @unique
desc             String
level            Int
atk              Int
def              Int
extraDeck        Boolean              @default(false)
cardType         cardTypeEnum
monsterType      monsterTypeEnum
monsterSubType   monsterSubTypeEnum
monsterAttribute monsterAttributeEnum
createdAt        DateTime             @default(now())
updatedAt        DateTime             @updatedAt
YuGiOhCardImage  YuGiOhCardImage\[\]
}

model YuGiOhCardImage {
id         String     @id @default(uuid())
cardName   YuGiOhCard @relation(fields: \[cardNameId\], references: \[id\])
cardNameId String     @default(uuid())
imageUrl   String
createdAt  DateTime   @default(now())
updatedAt  DateTime   @updatedAt
}

enum cardTypeEnum {
MONSTER
SPELL
TRAP
}

enum monsterTypeEnum {
Aqua
Beast
BeastWarrior
Cyberse
Dinosaur
DivineBeast
Dragon
Fairy
Fiend
Fish
Insect
Machine
Plant
Psychic
Pyro
Reptile
Rock
SeaSerpent
Spellcaster
Thunder
Warrior
WingedBeast
Wyrm
Zombie
}

enum monsterSubTypeEnum {
Normal
Effect
Flip
Gemini
Pendulum
Spirit
Toon
Tuner
Union
Fusion
Synchro
Xyz
Link
}

enum monsterAttributeEnum {
Dark
Divine
Earth
Fire
Light
Water
Wind
}
```

I store the images in a folder named public in the root source. The images are saved as jpeg files.

I looked up for that problem and got the info that you can make the images streamable to return these to the client but how do I do that?